# Can i use my old Acer laptop WIFI card in my Asus laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have a quick question, So I was wondering if I can use my Acer's WIFI Card in my Asus X502ca Laptop, I don't remember the Acer's model name as I got it from a friend to take parts from like the hard drive and ram for use in other stuff but since my Asus X502ca's WIFI Card has been giving me problems lately, I'm wondering if I can just take out the original card and use the card from the Acer? if so how would I go about it, do I just take out the original card pop in the Acer one and turn on the laptop and everything is fine? or is there other steps that I need to do?

Oh and both laptops run windows 10.

Thanks
-TopHat

Comment: Really depends if the old card has the same interface as the new card (usually PCIe Mini or M.2), and if they are the same you can always try. If both laptops run Windows 10 (and the Acer's card worked nicely with Windows 10), I don't see drivers being an issue. Generally Windows 7 hardware tends to work on Windows 10, the issues tend to be when you run newer hardware an old software or *really* old hardware on new software. You should try and see what model wireless card each one has (and post each of the model names if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Newer laptops have a BIOS lock on their wireless cards.  This is to prevent folks from swapping wireless cards between laptops.  You need to find out if the new ASUS laptop allows for wireless card swaps.  Then you need to find out if the old wireless card is compatible with the new ASUS slot for the card.  If all okay, you'll need to get the BIOS unlock code for the ASUS to allow the swap.  Then you'll need to get a Win8 or Win10 driver for that old wireless card... (Chances are, they stopped making a driver for that adapter back in Win7).  Regardless of my dark response, I wish you luck in your pursuit.  It would be much easier to purchase an Edimax AC1200 for USD15 and go about your business.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it to work, both cards are PCIe Mini I simply had to uninstall the Asus wireless drivers and install the wireless drivers for the Acer and it works just fine now, I was also able to get Bluetooth capabilities too the Asus laptop never came with it so I guess it's a added bonus, so yeah it works fine only difference is the network transfer speeds are a lot faster. Thanks for the help guys.